# How to apply size classes to a UIButton in Xcode

Tags: ios, interface-builder, size-classes

I want my button to have a size of **30x35** on iPhone and **60x70** on iPad. I create the button in a storyboard. I know what I need to use size classes. But I can't create different sizes on different devices. I use this sequence of actions:

1. Select iPad Pro 9,7 in storyboard.
2. Create button and change width **60**, height **70**.
3. Create width and aspects ratio constraints.
4. In width constraint unmark `Installed` press plus and create wR hR `Installed`.
5. Select iPhone 8 in storyboard.
6. Change width **30**, height **35**.
7. Create width constraints.

Sometimes I create different sizes on iPhone and iPad but sometimes this doesn't work.

Is this the right sequence of actions or not?

**Update**

Please tell me if I'm not right. For my button in iPad (60x70) I should create width constraint and press "installed" wR hR. For my button in iPhone (30x35) I should create one more width constraint and press "installed" for wC hC, wR hC, wC hR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **just** want to vary the width for iphone and ipad, JUST apply size class to your UIButton.

Go to `attributes inspector` of your button and click plus button to the left of width property.

Selected Width: Regular and Height: Regular. and tap on button `Add Variation`

[image]

### **Change the width for ipad (w R h R)**

Now, i my case, width will be `200` for **IPhone** and `400` for **IPad**

[image: applied width]

**Note**. You **don't need** to click on `installed` property even single time.

Do let me know if you need any help

Comment: I haven't problem with label. In my question I use button. Please read in my question text under **Update** title. I have problem with button

Comment: same concept applies for button also. just give it a shot.

Comment: Please tell me if I'm not right. For my button in iPad (60x70) I should create width constraint and press "installed" wR hR. For my button in iPhone (30x35) I should create one more width constraint and press "installed" for wC hC, wR hC, wC hR? **_Important_**: If I create only "installed" wR hR for iPad and for iPhone create just "installed" without any with and height in iPad I get 2 active constraints. Do you understand my problem or I should write more about it?

Comment: Could you show example in screenshots for button, please? Because it is difficult to understand in words. I not need example for label. I need example for constraints. I can not solve the problem whole day.

Comment: Could you help me with my problem? Why you not show example for button?

Comment: @User rather than demanding updates to answers _"Why you not show example for button?"_, why not try it out for yourself, with a button instead of a label?